# 'object' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments

Tags: constructor, xna, geometry, arguments

I'm trying my hand at generating spherical terrain in XNA 4.0, and am using an Icosahedron to achieve a sphere with evenly-distributed vertices.  I'm fairly new to Xna, and I'm running into this problem trying to create a class that will handle defining all the vertices for the sphere.

here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Icosahedron_Test
{
    class Icosahedron
    {

        public Icosahedron(int radius, int refinement, Vector3[] vertices)
            : base(radius, refinement, vertices)
        {
        }


    }
}
```

also, if anyone knows how to create an icosahedron, or can direct me to a tutorial, I'd be really grateful XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code example, you are defining a new class called Icosahedron.

The code you provided is called a Constructor, which is a special method that is used to instantiate new objects.

```
public Icosahedron(int radius, int refinement, Vector3[] vertices)
        : base(radius, refinement, vertices)
```

When writing

> : base( .... )

You are attempting to call a base call of the current class you're defining.

C# supports a mechanism called [Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which allows extending an object's behavior by extending another class. This can be used for adding/overriding some of the parent object's behavior and abilities.

In C#, all objects are derived from System.Object, and so, in your code you are attempting to call System.Object's constructor with 3 parameters, but this constructor method does not exist for System.Object.

You need to get a good reading on C# to get a grip on the basics :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Icosahedron` inherits `object`.

As the error message clearly states, you can't call `base(...)`, since `object` doesn't have such a constructor.

Comment: what is 'object' in this instance, and how would I go about correcting the problem?  (like I said, really new to this)

Comment: do you have any suggestion on how to fix it?

Comment: You need to learn C#.  Your `base` call does not make any sense

Comment: I did that based on the examples in the book I'm using.

Comment: @Patrick: You are probably missing a declaration after the class name eg. `class Icosahedron : ISomeInterface`